# Configuring security group or IP to ssh from specific instances (within same vpc)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to configure security group of an instance (say B) to allow SSH from another instance (say A).

Following are the 3 possible rules I can add to the Security Group of B to allow SSH from A:

1) Add public IP of A - Works 
2) Add private IP of A - Doesn't work 
3) Add security group id of a group with which A is associated - Doesn't work

Both instances and SGs are part of the same VPC.
Need to understand where I am going wrong.

My knowledge is based on [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html#security-group-rules) AWS doc. Specifically:

> "Another security group. This allows instances associated with the specified security group to access instances associated with this security group."

Comment: The question seems different but the answer seems similar... please check https://serverfault.com/a/996745/153161 for relevance to your scenario.

Comment: Are the two instances in the same security group?  If so, you shouldn't need to do anything since the security group would allow all traffic to flow between instances using the Private IP address.